# Get the intent from onCreate in Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I launch an activity from my widget using an Intent with some extra, anyway I can only get the Intent when the activity is in background.. How can I get the Intent when activity is created? Tried with this.getIntent() but extras are null.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your code?  I am able to get extras via `getIntent()` in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> How can I get the Intent when activity is created?

Call `getIntent()` on the `Activity`.

> Tried with this.getIntent() but extras are null.

One possibility is that you are arranging for an existing instance of the activity to return to the foreground (e.g., including `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`), in which case you will need to override `onNewIntent()` and collect the `Intent` there.

Another possibility is that you originally created a `PendingIntent` for the `Intent` with no extras, then later tried to create a new `PendingIntent` on an equivalent `Intent` (e.g., identifying the same activity) and included extras. In that case, you need to include `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` or `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` when creating the `PendingIntent`, so your new/changed extras are taken into account.

Comment: Hey is it necessary to receive the data in onCreate() method??

Comment: i mean can i use getIntent() before the onCreate()  so that the variable i am using to recieve becomes global?

Comment: something like this?

public class NowPlaying extends Activity implements Serializable  {
 
 
 Intent i = getIntent();
 final int position=i.getIntExtra("Data2", 0);
     
    final ArrayList<SongDetails> songs = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("Data1"); 
     
     
 
 
 
 
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Comment: Hello can anyone help me on my issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64492329/open-specific-custom-data-url-link-of-notification-received-from-firebase-messag